# CSS wizardy or JS required?

Tags: angularjs, css

I have been using Angular to try and fudge this...but I can't help but think it must be possible via CSS...

I have an arbitrary number of columns of width the width of each must be no less than 400px. If the screen will only accommodate 4.5 columns @ 400px then I would like the width to adjust to 450px or 25%

Unless the screen resolution is a smart phone in which case width should be 100%.

The columns must be ordered from left to right.

Floating LI's to the left at 400px doesn't work and I cannot use a % base because I don't know (in the context of CSS) how many will fit...

Perhaps I could hardcode media queries with conditional tests:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px)  {
    width: 100%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 1200px)  {
    width: 50%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 1600px)  {
    width: 25%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1600px) and (min-width: 2000px)  {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Basically, I am trying to make a grid, which maximizes screen space but collapses vertically as screen space lessens.

Any ideas? Masonary and similar JS libraries are not what I am after but I will consider implementing this in AngularJS if it's the best/only option???

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking? For an opinion? Masonry is used to stack unevenly sized objects into columns. Are you trying to create just a grid that depends on different screen sizes? Also, are those media queries correct? shouldn't it be min-width then max width? It seems your max width is always smaller than your min width

Comment: either you use media queries or write javascript that simulates media queries